# React NavBar Component Prevent render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am a new in React world in want to now why this code is always render every time i made a change on the page it always render the components that is no change made, for example:

```
<Grid columns="equal" className="app" style={{ background: secondaryColor.hex }}>
    <ColorPanel
      key={currentUser && currentUser.name}
      currentUser={currentUser} 
    />
      <SidePanel
        key={currentUser && currentUser.uid}
        currentUser={currentUser}
        primaryColor={primaryColor}
      />
    <Grid.Column style={{ marginLeft: 320 }}>
      <Messages
        key={currentChannel && currentChannel.id}
        currentChannel={currentChannel}
        currentUser={currentUser}
        isPrivateChannel={isPrivateChannel}
      />
    </Grid.Column>

    <Grid.Column width={4}>
      <MetaPanel 
        key={currentChannel && currentChannel.name}
        userPost={userPost}
        currentChannel={currentChannel}
        isPrivateChannel={isPrivateChannel} 
      />
    </Grid.Column>
       </Grid>
```

I made a change on the MessagePanel component and the entiry app render again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi can you test with the React Pure component class and React.memo functions, those functions help you to prevent re-render on the React components for example: If you have a class component you extends from PureComponent besides Components Pure component class do a shallow validation on the props of the component if a change is between the props the component is render againg, the same behavior is with the React.memo the only thing is the last one if for functional component here are the links of the React documentation:

React.memo example:

```
const NavMemo = React.memo(({ activeTab, onTabChange }) => {
  console.log('Render');
  return (
    <nav className="App-nav">
      <ul>
        <li className={`App-nav-item ${activeTab === 0 && 'selected'}`}>
          <a onClick={() => onTabChange(0)}>Items</a>
        </li>
        <li className={`App-nav-item ${activeTab === 1 && 'selected'}`}>
          <a onClick={() => onTabChange(1)}>Cart</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  );
});
```

React Pure Component Example:

```
export default class Nav extends React.PureComponent {
  render() {
    const { onTabChange, activeTab } = this.props;
    return (
      <nav className="App-nav">
        <ul>
          <li className={`App-nav-item ${activeTab === 0 && 'selected'}`}>
            <a onClick={() => onTabChange(0)}>Items</a>
          </li>
          <li className={`App-nav-item ${activeTab === 1 && 'selected'}`}>
            <a onClick={() => onTabChange(1)}>Cart</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    );
  }
}
```

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent